# Automatically disable a confirmed AWS Cognito user account after a period of inactivity

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I would like to know if AWS Cognito offers any facility where I can configure to disable a confirmed user if the user hasn't logged in for, say 60 days.

One way I thought of doing this is to keep track of the user's last logged-in date and calculate if it exceeds 60 days. If yes, then disable the account by using AdminDisableUserCommand from the SDK.

But before I do this I want to know if AWS offers any out-of-the-box solution to disable users who haven't logged-in for a while.

I saw the following link which talks about deleting an unverified user.
[How to delete a AWS Cognito user automatically after certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080372/how-to-delete-a-aws-cognito-user-automatically-after-certain-time)

But as my case slightly differs of actually disabling a confirmed user, I feel there might be some out-of-the-box solution provided where I do not have to rely on a Lambda trigger.

Is this possible?

Comment: You solution is the right one. Cognito does not currently have anything that you could use out-of-the-box to achieve what you need.